# Is there any concept in c++ like reflector in .Net?

Tags: .net, c++, dll, reflector

i like to get code from c++ dll ,i know we easily get from .Net dll by reflector. Is there any method available in c++ for this?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C++ is compiled directly to machine code. There's no intermediary language as in .NET. There are [some C++ disassemblers](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&expIds=17259,17315,23628,23670,24815,25834,25900,26328,26446,26515,26569&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=c%2B%2B+disassembler&cp=8&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=active&site=&source=hp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=c%2B%2B+disa&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=ab5cdb1806fef4aa) you may take a look at. [Hex-Rays decompiler](http://www.hex-rays.com/decompiler.shtml) is particularly good.

Comment: +1 as well for Hex-Rays! Just watched the vid (at their website) and it really looks like something I have long been searching for! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are talking about unmanaged C++. In that case, it is not possible. C++ is compiled into machine code unlike the managed languages which compile into an intermediate language which contain the metadata about the code which got compiled.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. Any 'reflection' must be through some hand coded mechanism.

Comment: I think Qt supports something like this.

Answer (score 1):

No, C++ has nothing like RedGate's reflector, and is incapable of such a thing.  A disassembler will not come close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Code for introspective capabilities can be generated from the output of Gcc-XML, or injected with OpenC++, but the C++ Standard itself doesn't require any particular facilities for this and no facilities/utilities for this are bundled with any popular compilers.  It's also possible for a C++ program to read the debugging information in its own executable file, but it's definitely not particularly portable, fast, or likely to make for a robust solution.