# How do you extract source code from a dll file?

Tags: c#, java, .net, dll

Is it possible to extract source code from a dll file which is create using Java or C++ or C or Python or Other languages ?

I am using .NetReflector to extract source code which is create using C# or VB.net.

if yes please give me tool`s name or tell how can i do this.

Thank`s.

Comment: Java doesn't make dll files. You also do understand that .NET dll's are nothing like C or C++ dll's, right? Have you done your homework on this first?

Comment: Pretty sure there are plenty of decompilers out there.

Comment: Python: UnPyc; .NET: Reflector; C++ / C: Luck; Java: JD.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for here is "decompiler".  You will need to be more specific as to which runtime you are using and i am sure a nicely crafted google search will do you well: http://bit.ly/zOU6mO.

Comment: Your question is really vague, and the languages you list will vary widely in how easy they are to decompile, and the quality of the results.  Moreover, it would help to know what you intend to do with the source code.

Answer (score 3):

A [DLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) is compiled code. You can use tools to de-compile them and get compiler-optimized code, but you cannot get your hands on the original code as it was written before being compiled.

Answer (score 0):

.NETReflector is for .NET and uses reflection to analyze .NET assemblies. For executables or libraries that were compiled from C or C++ you'll be hard pressed to get the actual source it was compiled from, since the executable/library is..well, just that, machinecode that can be executed. There's a big difference between that, and languages like C# and Java where an intermediate language comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

Post on Java Reflector: [Reflector for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722378/reflector-for-java).

Post on C++ Reflector: [Is there any concept in c++ like reflector in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715430/is-there-any-concept-in-c-like-reflector-in-net)

There are also addins for the .NETReflector.  Check out: http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/.  More specifically, there is an addin for C++.  Here is the direct link: http://www.sandpapersoftware.com/Main/Reflector.html.